# How to make auto CI build pipeline whenever a new branch is created?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration

i want Azure DevOps to create a CI build pipeline automatically whenever a new branch is committed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the triggers, they allow you to use wildcards so

[image]

would trigger a build for any branches that start with 'feature/'

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CI build pipeline by checking the 
**Enable continuous integration** option in the Triggers of build pipeline. Then add the new branch to the Branch filters.
[image]

If you are using yaml ,You can add the new branch directly to the trigger part of yaml.

[image]